# Lightning App Builder xml retrieve problem summer '21

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api, flexipages, lightning-app-builder, summer-21

after the Summer '21 release we have noticed that when we are trying to retrieve a flexipage that contains few lightning-web-component, all of these are removed from the retrieved manifest.

[image]

This happens for all lightning-web-component in our flexipages.
If we remove this configuration, we won't be able to install that configuration in other orgs.

How can we solve?
Anyone have the same problem?

Thanks in advance
Claudio

Answer (score 0):

This was a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001a1N4QAI&title=lwc-component-instances-are-dropped-from-flexipage-in-metadata-api-retrieve) with Summer '21.

There was initially this [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1010) created for the cli, but it is an issue with the Metadata API and will apply to change sets, ANT, or any mechanism that interacts with that API for retrieval/deployments.

**It has now been fixed with Summer '21 Patch 7.4**